# (Un)docking of editors in an eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

In an eclipse RCP application you can dock/undock views on default. 
But it seems you can't do the same with editors.

Is there any chance to configure such an application to (un)dock editors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO its not possible for Editors, its a known limitation of eclipse editors!

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse 3.x it is not possible, but 4.1 definitely has this feature (I just tried it). You can get it here: http://download.eclipse.org/e4/sdk/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ability to view editors side by side there are a few alternative options.

You can drag an editor "to the side" of an existing editor, making eclipse split the workbench page in two (or more), this is natively supported in RCP apps as well.

Another option is to create a separate workbench window (see Window -> New Window in Eclipse IDE). Once that is done, you can drag the editors between the windows. This works especially well if you work with several monitors. I'm guessing it should be possible to reuse the "New Window" action to make this happen in an RCP app as well.

The "new" window feature might be tweaked to make it seem like you can just drag an editor "off workbench" but I think that solution will be more painful than helpful.

Eclipse 4.x is said to have this ability but it isn't planned to ship until summer 2012.

It may be possible using the e4-project plugins, but I haven't tested.